# Finding common elements of a matrix between rows

Tags: algorithm, matrix

If there is a 4*2 matrix :
A = [1,2;3,4;5,6;7,1]
I need to find the rows which has atleast an element common between those rows. For example in the above eg, the 1 and 4 rows have 1 in common. This matrix rows can be of big length. What can be the best algorithm/logic for it

I tried the following algorithm :

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<N;j++){
        if(ipArr[i][0] == ipArr[j][0] || ipArr[i][0] == ipArr[j][1] ||
           ipArr[i][1] == ipArr[j][0] || ipArr[i][1] == ipArr[j][1]){
              //code to perform for repeating row, having atleast 1 common element.
        }
    }
}
```

For me the matrix has only 2 columns and it will be 2 only. It has N rows

It did not work out

Comment: Do you mean all row pairs that have an element in common? Or do you want a single pair of rows? Or do you want larger groups of rows that all share a common element? (None of these problems is easy, but the last one is a much harder, I think--and also would need further definition.) Also, what do you mean by "best"? Time performance? Memory use? Something else?

Comment: Its mainly an algorithm to classify and find how many groups of set of rows are having common elements, a group can have >=2 rows, I need to find each rows that are part of each group. more details the better.
In case if 1,2,3 rows have common elements, then 1,2,3 together form a group

Comment: The problem lacks some definition. Suppose you have rows (1, 2, 3), (2, 5, 6), (3, 5, 7). Each row has an element in common with each of the other two, but no element is common to all three. How should that get grouped? What about if the third row was (4, 5, 7), so it no longer had an element in common with (1, 2, 3)?

Comment: This sort of grouping here forms an implied grouping, all the above 9 elements fall under the same group. The commonness attribute is achieved if the elements exhibit commonness in atleast 2 rows i.e, >=2 rows. Mainly the goal is to find how many rows have repeatitive elements, it can be the same elements or different elements

Comment: Let me be sure I understand. If, say, I was classifying rows sequentially into groups, then a new row starts a new group only if it has no elements in common with any row of any existing group. On the other hand, if it has at least one element in common with at least one row of some group, it goes in that group. And if it has at least one element in common with rows from multiple groups, all those groups merge, along with the new row, into a single group. Is that right?

Comment: Actually every row mentions some number which points to a person, and every row shows some relationship between those persons who are represented by those numbers. So if few/ here 2 numbers appear in a row, those 2 people are similar, then forthcoming rows can have either of the previous row numbers, establishing similarities with some other number/person, which shows both that 1st row and this row have similar people indirectly. Finally I need to find how many rows have similar people...
I have edited my question as well with the code I tried

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a detailed algorithm for you, but I would approach this as a graph algorithm problem. Think of each row as a vertex of a graph. There is an edge between vertices if the two rows have at least one element in common. Then, if I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to find the connected components of the graph. (A connected component of a graph is a subgraph that has the property that all vertices in the subgraph are connected to each other by paths, and are not connected to any other vertices of the supergraph.)

This breaks down into two parts:

1. Find a way to compute whether two rows are joined by an edge, and build a graph representation based on that.
2. Find the connected components of the graph.

For the second part, there are standard algorithms, as discussed in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)). So let's turn to the first part.

One way to decide whether two rows have an element in common is to dump the elements into two set structures and check whether the intersection of the two sets is empty. Many programming languages have built-in collection data structures (usually based on hashes) to do this reasonably easily (in terms of programming effort). However, this is not going to be very efficient, particularly for large numbers of rows. But, it might be good enough for your purposes.

If time complexity is important, I would be inclined to try a slightly different method: sort each of the rows. This creates additional work at the beginning, but pays off as you compare all the rows pairwise. For instance, by comparing min and max values, you can quickly detect if two rows have disjoint ranges of values (and hence can't possibly have elements in common). Also, if the rows are sorted, you can (with some careful bookkeeping) do a coupled linear scan of both rows to search for common elements in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that your main purpose is to find the similarities between people as you had mentioned in the comments

Let each person(number) be a node and a row be the edge with weight 1.

Now build an undirected graph with this.

Let each node also store it's 'similarity' with every other node. This can be found by the shortest path from this node to every other node. (Requires O(n) space for each node)

Use Floyd Warshall algorithm for shortest path from one node to every other node.

If the shortest path is Inf it means there is no similarity and the minimum shortest path is maximum similarity

Time complexity: O(n^3) where n is number of people/numbers

Space complexity: O(n^2)